# What are good sources of free-to-use images and diagrams

Tags: book-recommendation

I am looking for good image repositories for biology teaching. Photos and textbook-like diagrams.

I am interested  in images that can be used commercially without payment, or, at least, that require a small one-time payment. They would be used in videos, not only on lectures, hence the worry about copyright.

Comment: i take it you mean on biology?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the videos are for a flipped/online course and posted on YouTube or Coursera?  I've done this. Biology is hard -- perhaps because I am picky and really want good images.

I used **Wikimedia.com** to search for many free images. I also contacted the publishers of the [free online version](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21054/) of **Molecular Biology of the Cell** and asked if I could use up to 20 for my free online course, and they agreed.

My university was also able to work out an agreement with the **textbook publisher** to use 200 of the textbook images for the Coursera course as long as they were credited, and a link to purchasing the textbook was available on the site. They want to keep my university happy as our students buy a truckload of books every year.

I've also gotten somewhat decent at using a **drawing tablet and powerpoint** image (boxes, circles) manipulation to make some of my own cell processes and chromosomes and such.

Lastly, [OpenStaxCollege.org](https://openstaxcollege.org/) has a wonderful collection of free textbooks for students, and they make their images available to faculty as free powerpoints. They aren't usually "good" enough to satisfy me, but definitely check them out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CC Search](http://search.creativecommons.org/). It allows you to find [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/) licensed content that you can use commercially.

[image]

Comment: Another interesting source is [somersault18:24](http://www.somersault1824.com/).

Answer (score 1):

An excellent source for images is the wellcome collections image library http://wellcomeimages.org/. You can negotiate commercial use with them, they are very reasonable, especially if it's for teaching purposes.