# Open database of medical images

Tags: database, data, biomedical-technology

Does anyone know of an open repository of medical images (e.g., CT scans) organized by disease category? I'm working on some computer vision software that requires a large set of controls from which to learn.

Comment: Try this -- http://www.nlm.nih.gov/NIHbmic/nih_data_sharing_repositories.html

Comment: Similar: [What are good sources of free-to-use images and diagrams](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/19227/6422)

Comment: Searchable database of Point of Care Ultrasound (POCUS) Images: https://www.grepmed.com/?q=POCUS

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/open-source-mri-image-dataset/13565#13565

Answer (score 6):

Open-access medical images:

1. **[MedPix](https://medpix.nlm.nih.gov/home)** (by keyword, organic system, pathology and diagnosis A-Z)
2. **[Radiopaedia](https://radiopaedia.org/)** (by keyword)
3. **[PEIR Radiology](http://peir.path.uab.edu/library/index.php?/category/106)** (by keyword, organ or anatomic region)
4. **[Ultrasound Cases](http://www.ultrasoundcases.info/)** (by keyword and organic system)
5. [Open Access Biomedical Image Search Engine (Openi)](https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/) (by keyword)
6. [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) (by keyword)
7. [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=919&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=BVIGXPT8NqLJrgTS16G4DQ&q=pneumonia%20%22creative%20commons%22&oq=pneumonia%20%22creative%20commons%22&gs_l=img.3...6606.17629..17877...0.0..0.102.1806.21j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i67j0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.43Sf7MaJckI) (using the filter "creative commons," "public domain" or "open access")
8. [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=919&tbs=sur%3Af%2Citp%3Aphoto%2Cic%3Agray&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=VlEGXNW0FMfMwQKrrLDgDw&q=liver%20absecss&oq=liver%20absecss&gs_l=img.3..0i10i24.32047.34490..34635...0.0..0.79.871.13......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i67j0i8i30j0i24.WMmIG3EVJZ8) (using filters: black/white, noncommercial, photo)

More:

- [Gray's Anatomy](https://www.bartleby.com/107/)
- [Dermatology Atlas](http://www.atlasdermatologico.com.br/)

Comment: +1 Nice collection. I won't add google image search in the list though.

Comment: I have used that search extensively with good results, because you can find pretty much all free images available on Internet in one go. And it's easy to narrow the search down.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good start: http://www.aylward.org/notes/open-access-medical-image-repositories. I understand that this question was somewhat googleable, but perhaps amassing a collection of curated resource links is constructive here since a search through the exchange revealed no prior inquiries into this topic.

Update:
For those who are interested in understanding the current landscape of tools available for analysis of medical images: Check out this list of open source tools (http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/opensource_mia_ws_2012/links.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like I already referenced on an [early post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19463/medical-image-dataset/53880#53880), there are several options on the [DICOM Library](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/). It is easy to find whatever image modality you want and also whatever disease category.