# What does lymph actually look like?

Tags: human-anatomy, tissue, lymphatic-system

I have scoured Google and a number of my anatomy textbooks for a picture of [**lymph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymph). However, I cannot find any such photo (or video) showing its actual appearance.

**Can someone provide a *reputable* image or source where a photograph of lymph can be seen?**

What I do know:

- Tortora & Derrickson (14th) A&P textbook mentions it consists of a "clear liquid extracellular matrix that is *similar* to blood plasma but with much less protein."
- A photo purporting to be lymph *does* [exist on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Homa_limfo_001.jpg), but lacking any further corroboration leads me to remain uncertain of the photo's authenticity.

Context:

I'm preparing a lecture for my 100 level college A&P course, and I was hoping to include a photo for my students to see and compare.

**NOTE**: I am hoping for a photo of lymph that is not classified as lipid-containing [*Chyle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyle), for which I can find [photos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyle#/media/File:Chylothorax.jpg). However, a comparison photo would be ok :)

Comment: http://www.ijcasereportsandimages.com/archive/2014/012-2014-ijcri/CR-10458-12-2014-osman/ijcri-1045812201458-osman-full-text.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be one of rare actual photos of lymph online (suggested in the comment above):

[image]

Image: Lymph (source: [IJCRI - Case Reports Journal](http://www.ijcasereportsandimages.com/archive/2014/012-2014-ijcri/CR-10458-12-2014-osman/ijcri-1045812201458-osman-full-text.php))‎

This particular lymph (or "lymph fluid" or "lymphatic fluid") was aspirated from a "lymphocele", which is an abnormal collection of lymph in the body (appearing outside of the normal lymphatic system).

While a lymphocele is not normal, the lymph in it, such as in this photo, looks quite normal: it is a clear (translucent) and yellowish liquid.

> The lymphatic (lim-FAT-ik) system is a network of tubes that collects
>   lymph (LIMF). This **clear, pale yellow fluid** drains out of blood
>   vessels all over the body. *([KidsHealth.org](https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/lymphatic-malformations.html))*

The froth is from proteins as they normally appear in the lymph.

The [image of lymph in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Homa_limfo_001.jpg) is not a clear lymph, but obviously a chyle (a milky fluid containing the lymph and chylomicrons due to thoracic duct injury).

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm not familiar with the *International Journal of Case Reports and Images*, but this is certainly better than I found (and, if I determine it to be reputable -- which I don't doubt -- it's a great new source for clinical images to infuse into my course lectures!)

Comment: @theforestecologist, if you need more medical images: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38774/open-database-of-medical-images/79533#79533

Comment: Now *this* is the type of Q&A/discussion that this site is supposed to emphasize! I love learning new resources. Thanks again for your informational responses and help :).